# C: Making an equation appears only once

Tags: c

I have following C code. The statement calculating ***simple_root*** appears twice. I am wondering if there is a better way to organise the code making the statement appear only once.

If putting the ***simple_root*** after the last ***else***, there is a risk of error, e.g. the previous two conditions doesn't match. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
if(fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_1)) < 1e-6)
{
    triple_root = secDerivRoot_1;
    simple_root = -b/a - 3*triple_root;
}
else if (fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_2)) < 1e-6)
{
    triple_root = secDerivRoot_2;
    simple_root = -b/a - 3*triple_root;
}       
else 
    printf("Something is wrong. No common root with its 2nd derivative. \n");
```

Comment: please publish the code with which it  can be easily understandable as there is no statement to print simple_root and no definition of fab function

Comment: @AmitojSingh, `fabs` is in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something in the comment

> If putting the simple_root after the last else, there is a risk of error, e.g. the previous two conditions doesn't match

This is already the case - if you don't match those two then `triple_root` and `simple_root` are already not set.  I'm not sure how they are used after this piece of code or what your error handling is.  You can either return immediately after the `printf` statement or set `triple_root` to be a `NaN`.

Then you can move the simple_root equation below the `if` statement.  Alternatively you could put that in to a function.  A one line function is fine and can make the code easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should do it. I haven't compiled it or tested it so you may need to tweak something.

However your original formulation is much more readable and I really see no advantage to doing it this way.

And with this approach you are always doing both of the `quartic_polynomial()` calls rather than sometimes only doing one which may be much worse computationally speaking so far as CPU usage and time than duplicating a line of code.

I am curious if the two `if` statements could both be true. What are you to do in a case like that or can you just choose which ever you like?

```
{
    int sec_1 = (fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_1) < 1e-6);
    int sec_2 = (fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_2) < 1e-6);

    if (! (sec_1 || sec_2)) {
        printf("Something is wrong. No common root with its 2nd derivative. \n");
    } else {
        if (sec_1)
            triple_root = secDerivRoot_1;
        else
            triple_root = secDerivRoot_2;
        simple_root = -b/a - 3*triple_root;
    } 
}
```

Another approach, if a desire to prevent one statement from being updated and the other not would be something like the following:

```
#define SIMPLE_ROOT_CALC  simple_root = -b/a - 3*triple_root

if(fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_1)) < 1e-6)
{
    triple_root = secDerivRoot_1;
    SIMPLE_ROOT_CALC;
}
else if (fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_2)) < 1e-6)
{
    triple_root = secDerivRoot_2;
    SIMPLE_ROOT_CALC;
}       
else 
    printf("Something is wrong. No common root with its 2nd derivative. \n");
```

or even something like:

```
#define ROOT_CALC(x)  triple_root = (x); simple_root = -b/a - 3*triple_root;

if(fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_1)) < 1e-6)
{
    ROOT_CALC(secDerivRoot_1);
}
else if (fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_2)) < 1e-6)
{
    ROOT_CALC(secDerivRoot_2);
}       
else 
    printf("Something is wrong. No common root with its 2nd derivative. \n");
```

or perhaps depend on evaluation short circuit with the logical Or operator:

```
{
    double x;
    if (! (((x = secDerivRoot_1), fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_1) < 1e-6)) || ((x = secDerivRoot_2), fabs(quartic_polynomial(a, b, c, d, e, secDerivRoot_2) < 1e-6) )) ) {
        printf("Something is wrong. No common root with its 2nd derivative. \n");
    } else {
        triple_root = x;
        simple_root = -b / a - 3 * triple_root;
    }
}
```